# How to trigger Path Variable in Pojo Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, annotations

All i'm new on spring boot and trying to do some new. currently i have 3 pojo class which extend's in the user class.  I'm trying to assign the value of may @PathVariable partnerid in all class of setter id method like below.
My question is, is spring boot provided  any @annotation that trigger my variable into my Partner class.
I'm trying to update my user request by adding the partner id in setter method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/push/fire/")
public class PushIdController {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PushIdController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/partner/{partnerId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @annotation("new Partner().setPartnerId("PathVariable value")")
    public User userLogin(@PathVariable("partnerId")  String partnerId, @RequestBody User user){

        return user;

    }
}
```

Partner Class

```
public class Partner {

    private String partnerId;

    public String getPartnerId() {    return partnerId; }
    public void setPartnerId(String partnerId) { 
        this.partnerId = partnerId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Partner{" + "partnerId='" + partnerId + '\'' + '}';}
}
```

User Class

```
public class User {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(User.class);

    private String userId;
    private Role role;
    private Video video;

     public void setUserId(String userId) {
        log.info("set-User-id");
        // getPartnerId null
        this.userId = userId + "_" + getPartnerId() ;
    }
    public void setRole(Role role) {
        log.info("set-User-Role");
        this.role = role;
    }

    public void setVideo(Video video) {
        log.info("set-User-Video");
        this.video = video;
    }
}
```

Role Class

```
public class Role {

    private String roleId;

    public void setRoleId(String roleId) {
        // getPartnerId null
        this.roleId = roleId + "_"  +  getPartnerId();
    }

}
```

Video Class

```
public class Video {

    private String videoId;

    public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
        this.videoId = videoId + "_"  + getPartnerId();
    }
}
```

Json Request:-

```
{
    "userId": "1d3ejjj",
    "userName": "Nabeel.amd93@gmail.com",
    "phone": "03153817177",
    "role": {
         "roleId": "d423",
          "name": "nabeel ahmed"
    },
    "video": {
        "videoId": "123456d",
        "h": "25",
        "w": "25"

    }
}
```

Json Response:-

```
{
    "userId": "1d3ejjj_1d2d6dq0jhjhk",
    "userName": "Nabeel.amd93@gmail.com",
    "phone": "03153817177",
    "role": {
         "roleId": "d423_1d2d6dq0jhjhk",
          "name": "nabeel ahmed"
    },
    "video": {
        "videoId": "123456d_1d2d6dq0jhjhk",
        "h": "25",
        "w": "25"

    }
}
```

as we know when we hit the request the Json assign into the Pojo calling setter method during method call i just want to update the id's of each class's.
I'd want to re-update like below

```
user.setUserId(user.getUserId+"_"+partnerId);
user.getVideo().setVideoId(user.getVideo().getVideoId+"_"+partnerId);
```

and soo on.....

Comment: This is an extended duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50303385/1082681). Furthermore, you say that you have POJO classes extending the `User` class. This is not true according to your sample code. Finally, it is still unclear what you are asking. So I have to say sorry, I still cannot help you. BTW, you cannot put Java code inside a string as an annotation parameter and expect it to be compiled and run on the fly. If you could just explain what you want to achieve, maybe someone could suggest a way to do it. No offense, but your explanation is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

All After a lot of search i found the way for trigger the path variable into Pojo class.

The @annotation call the "InitBinder"
Spring provides @InitBinder annotation that identifies methods which initializes the WebDataBinder and this WebDataBinder populates the arguments to the annotated methods. Hence, the easy way is to register some custom editors in Spring. so i create my partner object into the method by getting the value of request parameter.
**NOTE:- As i post on the top i forgot the add the static key word with variable partnerId**

Partner Class

```
public class Partner {

    public static String partnerId;

    public static String getPartnerId() {    return partnerId; }
    public void setPartnerId(String partnerId) {
       this.partnerId = partnerId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "Partner{" + "partnerId='" + partnerId + '\'' + '}';}
    }
}
```

After data i add this method in my controller like

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder webdataBinder) {
    webdataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new PartnerFireId());
}
```

And the PartnerFireId class like

```
public class PartnerFireId extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private Partner partner;

    public void setAsText(final String partnerKey) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        partner = new Partner();
        partner.setPartnerId(partnerKey);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/enums-as-request-parameters-in-spring-boot-rest